# Cannot Get PiPlay (formerly piMAME) to work

Tags: raspbian, emulation

Alright so I have a RPi B+ model that I have installed rasbian and then  piPlay on. The issue is, when I put .zip rom files into the roms folder for mame4all, non of the games will work. Also, I dont see a directory for games that might run on advanceMame. So simply stated, I would like either an explanation of how I can get this to work and what type of roms I need (as I know there are different formats), or an alternative method to emulating old arcade games on MAME.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't solve your problem but i can show you an alternativ.
Try to user emulationstation this a cross-platform graphical front-end for emulators with controller navigation.
http://emulationstation.org/ It works nice for me :) Sure, you'll find some tutorial on web... Have fun

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using PiPlay very long but I think you have to add ROMs via the web interface from another machine.

When you set up PiPlay you should be able to see the IP address in the top right corner of the screen. Using a computer on the same network, navigate to the IP address and you should see the web interface for PiPlay on your Raspberry Pi. It should be pretty easy from there to find how to add ROMs.

I have a vague idea that you have to add ROMs this way to make sure they are added to your local PiPlay database.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [RecalBox](https://www.recalbox.com/), it's easy to install and to setup. Has lots of useful features and even more emulators, not just MAME.